# Image processing: Line detection on paper images

Tags: image-processing

I have some [Beta Radiographed](http://cameo.mfa.org/wiki/Beta_radiography) papers which all have some vertical lines. I'd like to use the image processing capabilities of Mathematica to automatically detect these vertical lines.

The code which I wrote detects the lines, but when I run the same code on another set of data, I have to manually adjust the `Binarize` threshold to get decent results. I know I can use `Manipulate` but I want to save my time in checking each value to see if it detects the vertical lines.

Is there a way in which the operation of detecting these lines in all the beta radiographed data can be automated?

[image]

Comment: Since you are James Bond you might ask Q if he can do that easily. If not, I doubt there is a way to automate it.

Comment: `Normalize = Normalize[{{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}}, Norm];` gives an error.

Comment: Sorry, you will need to change it to Normal = Normalize[{{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}}, Norm], Since Normalize is reserved.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a complete answer, but I think you can build on this idea (I currently have no time to push it further).

Considering that the lines are really vertical:

```
imageData = ImageData[imgRaw];
data = Sum[First /@ imageData[[i]], {i, Length[imageData]}];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

We can see that there are local minimums. I had no time to automate the detection of this local minimum (as per comments, in version 10, this should be easy with `FindPeaks`).

So, with no automation, I'm taking the minimums manually from the "get coordinates" tool:

```
linesCoordinates = First /@ {{58.11, 382.5}, {228.7, 361.2}, {391.6, 446.5}, {568.5, 
 622.4}};
imageDataAux = imageData;
Do[imageDataAux[[All, Round[i]]] = {0, 0, 0}, {i, linesCoordinates}]
Image[imageDataAux]
```

[image]

Looks promising. Obviously, reducing the analysis to an horizontal band that doesn't have the handwriting may help on the method precision. I hope this helps.

Comment: you say: "I had no time to automate the detection of this local minimum...". In MMA10  this can be done with function `FindPeaks`

Comment: @molekyla777 I know... But I'm still working with 9 (waiting for 10.0.2 to have 10 on my production machine)

Comment: `peaks = {#[[1]], -#[[2]]} & /@ FindPeaks[-data, 5, 2]` works perfectly with your data!

Comment: Hey, I tried the above info but got some error in data = Sum[First /@ imageData[[i]], {i, Length[imageData]}]; and in Image[imageDataAux] no image was displayed as an output.

I then changed my data set and in other image there was no plotting in the listline. Can you help further? thanks.

Comment: @JamesBond sure. Can you send me one of the images by e-mail (see in my account)? That way, i'm sure we are seing the same thing. What M version do you have?